# Moving From ASP.Net 3.5 to 4.0 - System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission Exception

Tags: .net, asp.net, security, asp.net-4.0

I'm sure this can't be too hard; but I'm struggling.  The error is

> Exception Details:
>   System.Security.SecurityException:
>   Request for the permission of type
>   'System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission,
>   mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'
>   failed.

I'm trying to write to a text file on the server.  Before, I had to modify the `web.config` file set the trust level to full.  Then it all seemed to work.

I've since updated my site to use ASP.NET 4.0; and now I can't pull it off.  I'm really not doing much at all, just reading/writing a file.  But now I can't get past the error.  From what I've read, it sounds like 'Full' is the default setting in 4.0?

I have a (virtually) empty web.config.  I tried adding the trust level to explicitly set it to full but it didn't seem to help.

**EDIT**

I'm currently using `File.AppendAllText`  to write to the file and `File.ReadAllText` to read the contents.

And this is IIS7.

If it sounds like this isn't programming related, I can take it up with customer support for my host.  But, like I said, if I switch my site back to 3.5 it works great.  When I set it to 4.0 - I get this error.

Comment: Is this hosted on IIS6 or IIS7?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a whitepaper on many of the breaking changes in ASP.NET 4.0
http://www.asp.net/learn/whitepapers/aspnet4/breaking-changes

It looks like the security model had a significant overhaul...but it looks like the short answer for my problem is to add:

```
   <trust level= "Full" legacyCasModel="true" />
```

legacyCasModel should give you the old behavior from previous editions of ASP.NET.  This worked for me.